# I/O pending error while reading data from serial port

Tags: c, io, serial-port

I have a C program that trying to read data from COM Port in windows.
I am able to write the data on com port but not able to read it.
This is my read function? if anyone could take a look and point me to correct direction.
I am starting a seperate thread in main method

------ Code of main method function ------

```
if(!SetCommMask(hSerial,eventFlags)){
    printf("Error in setting the event maskwith error: %d \n",GetLastError());}
_beginthread(*readDataFromPort,0,NULL);
```

----- Code of read data function  ------

```
void readDataFromPort(void*)
{
    DWORD dwReadResult;
    bool waitOnRead = FALSE;
    bool abContinue = TRUE;

    memset(&ovRead,0,sizeof(ovRead));
    ovRead.hEvent = CreateEvent(0,TRUE,0,0);
    if(ovRead.hEvent == NULL){
        fprintf(stderr,"Error creating overlapped event for reading");
    }
    //Reading data from port
    while (true){
            //Changed the overlap to NULL
            if(WaitCommEvent(hSerial,&eventFlags,NULL)){
                if(GetCommMask(hSerial,&dwMask)){
                    ResetEvent(ovRead.hEvent);              
                if(dwMask == EV_RXCHAR){
                    printf("character arrived");
                }
            }
            memset(tmp,0,sizeof(tmp));

            if(!ReadFile(hSerial, tmp, sizeof(tmp), NULL, &ovRead)){
                if(GetLastError()!=ERROR_IO_PENDING){
                    printf("error io pending: Error is %d\n",GetLastError());
                    break;
                }else{
                    waitOnRead=TRUE;    
                }
            }
            if(waitOnRead){
                dwReadResult = WaitForSingleObject(ovRead.hEvent,10000);
                switch(dwReadResult){
                case WAIT_OBJECT_0:
                    if(!GetOverlappedResult(hSerial,&ovRead,&dwBytesRead,TRUE)){
                        printf("Damn error again :-(");
                    }else{  
                        if(dwBytesRead>0){
                            ++Rx;
                            printf("Tx - %d: Rx - %d\n",Tx,Rx);
                            printf("%s",tmp);
                        }                                               
                    }
                }                           
            }
            waitOnRead=FALSE;
        }   
        if(strlen(tmp)>0 && inLoop){
            writeDataToPort(*tmp);
        }
    }
    CloseHandle(ovRead.hEvent); 
    _endthread();
}

> Blockquote
```

Comment: Not certain `ReadFile(0` will provide a `'\0'` terminated string in `tmp`.  Suggest passing the address of `DWORD length` instead of `NULL` and use that `tmp` and `length` when calling `writeDataToPort()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

_beginthread(*readDataFromPort,0,NULL);

This snippet starts the thread regardless of SetComMask outcome, but if you are reading OK must have worked. 
Check out MSDN threaded port read/write which works (VC5 compile worked straight off out of the box) above code looks really similar though, is it same?.